# Service Fabric "Container deployment is not supported on the node" on Azure Stack

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-stack

We are trying to deploy a Docker Container on a Service Fabric running on Azure Stack.
Unfortunately, it constantly fails with the error message `Container deployment is not supported on the node`. The container is not pulled or even started.

We don't see any reason why the container does not start:

- The host os is "WindowsServer2016 DataCenter with Containers"
- We can log onto the nodes and pull and execute the container on the nodes successfully
- We have the problem for all containers
- We tried both hyperv and process isolation mode

We have set up the very same configuration in the cloud and the container executes without problems:

- Same OS-Version and even build number: version 1607 build 14393.4825
- Same ServiceFabric-Version: 8.2.1363.9590

Does anybody know this issue? Might it be related to using the Azure Stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out ourselves. One has to check the cluster manifest, whether there is a property called "DisableContainers". In our case it was set to true, thus not allowing container deployments on the cluster node. Updating the service manifest via PowerShell with the correct setting solved the issue.

The trick was, that the official [MS docs](http://see%20here:%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-fabric-settings) tells us that the default value is FALSE. The property is not listed in our public cluster due to its default state.
On the Azure Stack, on the other hand, it is set to TRUE without explanation even if you explicitly deploy on nodes with Docker support.